# Efficient way to do str.contains on pandas data frame for 10 million patterns and get matches for each

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame called 'subset' and I want to count the number of rows whose column 'sequence' contains each of the patterns in the set called motifs. I have done it using a for loop, iterating through the set of motifs and identifying matches for each. However, this set is huge and I have 10 million motifs and it is taking a really long time to complete the step. Is there a more efficient way of doing str.contains for 10 million patterns?

Here is my code:

```
motif_background = {}
for motif in motifs: ### loop through set of 12,000,000 motifs
 match = subset['sequence'].str.contains(motif).sum() ### get the number of rows whose 'sequence' column contains  the motif 
 motif_background[motif].append(match)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a larger dataset like yours, you could use multiprocessing to compute the results faster, parallely on multiple-cores.

Here is the working code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os
import numpy as np

pool = Pool(os.cpu_count())
split_df_results = pool.map(fn_to_execute, np.array_split(df, num_cores))
df = pd.concat(split_df_results)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```